# how to prove homomorphism of groups with real numbers

Tags: group-homomorphism

I have this,
Let $\phi: G_1 → G_2$ defined by $\phi(x) = 2^x$ , where $G_1$ is a group of real numbers under addition and $G_2$ is a group of non-zero real numbers. How to show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism?

I know I need to prove this, $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$

Comment: Well, what methods do you know for showing something is a homomorphism? Have you tried just showing that it satisfies the definition of homomorphism?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited the question

Comment: $$2^{x+y}=2^x\times 2^y$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group operation on $G_1$ is addition, but the group operation on $G_2$ is multiplication. So what you have to show (among other things) is that
$$\phi(x+y) = \phi(x) \times \phi(y)$$